# Obter os últimos N caracteres de uma string

Tags: c#

Tenho uma `string` que na realidade é um *número de telefone*. Mas um número de telefone pode ter alguns formatos como:

```
+55 34 98989898

34 989898

989898
```

A constante é que sempre os 8 últimos números são os números do telefone, queria saber como separo esses 8 últimos números do restante.  Exemplo:

```
numero = "+55 34 98989898"
```

***Virar***

```
n1 = "+55 34 ";
n2 = "98989898";
```

Poderia usar o *SubString*? E como?

Comment: Não sabe usar o Substring? Seria isso?

Comment: Nesse caso não, não sei como vou fazer para pegar como referência os 8 últimos caracteres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for nesse formato:

```
string telefone = "+55 34 98989898";

Console.WriteLine(telefone.Substring(telefone.Length - 8));
```

[*Link do Demo*](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kif8Rf)

Answer (score 5):

> A constante é que sempre os 8 últimos números são os números do
>   telefone, queria saber como separo esses 8 últimos números do
>   restante.

Utilize o `Substring` utilizando como parâmetro o tamanho de sua variável menos a quantidade de caracteres que você quer capturar.

Lembre-se antes de verificar se o tamanho da `string` contem a quantidade de caracteres desejado.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var telefone = "123 12345678";
        Console.WriteLine(telefone);        
        if(telefone.Length > 8) 
               Console.WriteLine(telefone.Substring(telefone.Length -8)); //12345678
    }
}
```

Código no .net FIDDLE
https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMAnYN

> numero = "+55 34 98989898"
>
> Virar n1 = "+55 34 "; n2 = "98989898";

Caso sua variável contenha sempre este formato, você pode utilizar o método `Split` utilizando o espaço como parâmetro:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var telefone = "+55 81 12345678";
        Console.WriteLine(telefone);    

        var telefoneSeparado = telefone.Split(' ');

        Console.WriteLine("CD País: " + telefoneSeparado[0]); //+55     
        Console.WriteLine("DDD: " + telefoneSeparado[1]); //81      
        Console.WriteLine("Número: " + telefoneSeparado[2]); //12345678
    }
```

Código no .net FIDDLE: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4qHIJM

Caso a sua variável não tenha um formato específico, você pode utilizar o método `String.Remove` que funciona de forma semelhante ao `String.Substring`

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var telefone = "+55 81 12345678";
        Console.WriteLine(telefone); //+55 81 12345678      

        Console.WriteLine(telefone.Substring(telefone.Length -8)); //2345678

        Console.WriteLine(telefone.Remove(telefone.Length - 8)); //+55 81 

    }
```

Código funcionando no .NET Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hna8yD

Answer (score 4):

Gosto da abordagem por expressão regular.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([\d]{8})");
var match = regex.Match("+55 34 98989898");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value); // Imprime "98989898"
}
```